# Power Query error - Unable to get the NumberFormat property of the Range class

Tags: excel, powerquery, vba

I can't find any search results on this error:

```
Unable to **get** the NumberFormat property of the Range class
```

There are tons of search results about this Excel error:

```
Unable to **set** the NumberFormat property of the Range class
```

Here is error screenshot.

[image]

I am getting this error when refreshing Power Query using VBA, but not when refreshing query directly:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet").Range("myQueryRange").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh
```

This is the error message:

```
Error Message:

Unable to get the NumberFormat property of the Range class

Stack Trace:

Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.Com.ComWrapperException: Unable to get the NumberFormat property of the Range class ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unable to get the NumberFormat property of the Range class
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.Com.ComWrapper.InvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Renderers.TableRenderer.ApplyColumnFormats(IListObject listObject, FillColumnType[] columnTypes, FillColumnType[] previousColumnTypes)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Renderers.TableRenderer.ApplyFormatting(IApplication application, IListObject listObject, FillColumnType[] columnTypes, IEnumerable`1 recordFieldTypes, FillColumnType[] previousColumnTypes)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.AddInFillServices.<>c__DisplayClass19.<PerformPostRefreshFixups>b__17()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.BufferedPainter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<TryPaint>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.BufferedPainter.TryPaint(Func`1 paintAction)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.BufferedPainter.TryPaint(IApplication application, Func`1 paintAction)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.RefreshFillSession.CompleteRefresh(IWorkbook workbook, Boolean onTimer)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.RefreshFillSession.UpdateRefreshStatus(IWorkbook workbook, Boolean onTimer)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.RefreshFillSession.ResumeFill(Boolean onTimer)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.UpdateQueries()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.<OnFillUpdateTimerTick>b__5()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)

Invocation Stack Trace:

   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Any ideas on what is happening?

My environment:

Windows 7
Excel 2010 64 bit
Power Query Version: 2.29.4217.1861

Comment: I've no idea, but the Microsoft guys who sometimes reply here will likely want your Excel and Power Query version details.

Answer (score 0):

If you can click that send-a-frown button, can you send the error details to our excellent troubleshooting team? Maybe we've seen it before, but I don't see any issue in our bug database filed for this.

(To save you some time, the first thing we'll probably recommend is to try updating Power Query add-in. The latest version is at 2.32.)

Comment: Unfortunately we use Lotus Notes so the send a frown doesn't work to open email. Also I have limited admin rights and can't update Power Query in immediate future.

Comment: Can you gather your M query, trace files and stack trace and send it to pq2fb@microsoft.com ? (To enable tracing: Power Query ribbon -> Options -> Diagnostics -> Enable Power Query tracing checkbox. You can find the trace logs by clicking the Open traces folder link. )